# How much authentication is necessary with Restful PUT/POST?

Tags: rest

I have a single organization that needs to send me a predetermined set of very sensitive data. My current process looks like this,

1. Created web page https://mywebsite.com/random/
2. The page requires HTTPS and only accepts POST/PUT requests or it redirects
3. The first thing I do is check for two variables, "unique_id_1" and "unique_id_2". Each of those variables must match exactly to accounts already in my database.

At this point, a malicious person would have to first find the web page, then have to figure out the name for those two variables and also fill them with the correct matching data. How likely would that scenario play out?

I've thought about adding a 3rd variable, "shared_key" and then share a string of text with the submitter to include with every PUT/POST request. How helpful would this be?

Another thought I had was both of us writing a date hashed with a pre shared key. They send the variable and I match it against my own. That way the key changes every single day. Overkill?

What about Basic Authentication, is it even that secure? I currently reject and redirect incorrect visitors/data. It would seem that the website asking for authentication would only do more to tip off potential hacking programs.

Comment: The date hashed with a pre-shared key is a good approach that I've seen used.  Possibly you might want to make the key a parameter per organization, just in case some day you want to get another organization to send you the same data on the same interface.

Answer (score 0):

> It would seem that the website asking for authentication would only do
>   more to tip off potential hacking programs.

This is a *terrible* reason to not implement authentication. You don't need to do it for the whole site, you can do it for just your API endpoint.

If your data is "very sensitive" you might want to consider some or all of the following in addition to HTTPS:

- Make sure your HTTPS itself is secure with [the Qualsys checker](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/).
- Have the API user register their IP address and lock down the service so that it answers only to that IP.
- Require a client certificate (that you create), like with `SSLVerifyClient require`.
- Use basic or digest authentication on top of the request. This obviates the need for your id1/id2 parameters.
- If you feel sufficiently motivated, implement OAuth.
- Instead of your 3rd "shared key" parameter, implement [URL signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7010786/url-signing-with-hmac-or-openssl).

Also:

- Don't compare a hash of a client date against a hash of server date. It will break near midnight, especially if client and server are in different timezones or have drifting clocks.

Comment: I did some [more reading](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/988/is-basic-auth-secure-if-done-over-https) and Basic Authentication doesn't seem to add much in the way of security over just including a password in the POST body. IP addresses can be [spoofed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing) on one way communucation like REST. HMAC (what you linked to) was how I was planning on encrypting the date. I was planning on generating two dates to match against, yesterday and today, that way I was covered on time changes. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: Basic Auth is an established convention that you shouldn't try to reinvent, and implementing it won't require any additional work for the client because everything already supports it. It also has the advantage of being out-of-band from the point of view of the REST payload. (Like authentication should be.) Regarding IP filtering, saying you shouldn't implement it because IPs can be spoofed is like saying you shouldn't lock your doors because locks can be picked. Also, generating two dates still won't solve the midnight issue -- you'll get yesterday and today versus today and tomorrow.